# Commutation relations for fermionic and bosonic creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, bosons

I'm trying to calculate commutator:
$$ [a_{k}^{\dagger}a_k,a_{k'}^{\dagger}a_{k'+q}b_q^{\dagger}]_{\_} $$
where $a_k$, $a_k^{\dagger}$ - annihilation and creation operators for fermions, $b_q^{\dagger}$ - creation operator for bosons.
Can I write the following?
$$ [a_{k}^{\dagger}a_k,a_{k'}^{\dagger}a_{k'+q}b_q^{\dagger}]_{\_} =[a_{k}^{\dagger}a_k,a_{k'}^{\dagger}a_{k'+q}]_{\_}b_q^{\dagger}  $$
I would be glad for explanation. Regards.